# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'accentColor'

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I have seen a number of SO questions about this error, but all of them had a common problem, which is that they were trying to use v21 attributes on older versions or they had a lower `targetSDKVersion`, but that is not the case in my app.

***Note:*** I deleted the already present folders `values-v11` and `values-v14` from the project, if that matters.

The **compiler error** is as follows:

```
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] D:\CodingMyHeart\WORKSPACES\EclipseWorkspaces\Workspace of Android Practice One\MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree\res\values\styles.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'accentColor'.
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] 
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] D:\CodingMyHeart\WORKSPACES\EclipseWorkspaces\Workspace of Android Practice One\MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree\res\values\styles.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'primaryColor'.
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] 
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] D:\CodingMyHeart\WORKSPACES\EclipseWorkspaces\Workspace of Android Practice One\MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree\res\values\styles.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'primaryColorDark'.
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] 
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] D:\CodingMyHeart\WORKSPACES\EclipseWorkspaces\Workspace of Android Practice One\MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree\res\values-v21\styles.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:accentColor'.
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] 
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] D:\CodingMyHeart\WORKSPACES\EclipseWorkspaces\Workspace of Android Practice One\MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree\res\values-v21\styles.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:primaryColor'.
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] 
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree] D:\CodingMyHeart\WORKSPACES\EclipseWorkspaces\Workspace of Android Practice One\MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree\res\values-v21\styles.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:primaryColorDark'.
[2015-08-08 14:30:23 - MaterialDesignGoogleNowLikeSearchBoxThree]
```

I have `appcompat_v7` already included in the project, and there is another library named `android-support-v7-appcompat` available:

[image]

***SSCCE:***

**res/values/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#64FFDA</color><!-- Light ferozi -->
    <color name="primaryColorDark">#1DE9B6</color><!-- Darker ferozi -->
    <color name="accentColor">#E94F37</color><!-- Close to red -->
</resources>
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="primaryColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="primaryColorDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="accentColor">@color/accentColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**res/values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:primaryColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:primaryColorDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:accentColor">@color/accentColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.materialdesigngooglenowlikesearchboxthree"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.materialdesigngooglenowlikesearchboxthree.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the properties wrong. It is **`colorPrimary`** and not `primaryColor`. Follow [this.](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

**Edit**  - For your reference

```
<resources>
<!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Edit**

`ActionBar` properties are different than `AppCompat` properties. You have to explicitly give theme properties like [this.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
       parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**But** its advisable to use ToolBar. which has lot of features and which be used as per your `style`. This one is typical example for `ToolBar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

For more you can refer [this.](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: Hey this has resolved the error. But those colors are Not being applied. It's just picking up the light or dark actionbar color depending on whether I am using the base `AppCompat.Light` or `AppCompat.Dark` theme. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using default `actionBar` or `toolbar`?

Comment: Default ActionBar. I did not add any code to anything. You can see the above SSCCE.